# Java how to read text just from a node but not from his child

Tags: java

I need to read just ElementByTagName("id")l   ;
When i get the NodeList  elements  byTagname(id) it returns the details too

```
<Movie_List>
        <category>
            <id id="idAction">Action  <----- I have to read just This
                <details>some details</details> <-- not both of them
            </id>
        </category>
    </Movie_List>
```

this

```
 NodeList nodeStruct = myDoc.getElementsByTagName("Movie_List");             
    for(int i = 0 ; i < nodeStruct.getLength() ; i++){
        Node myNode = nodeStruct.item(i);
        if(myNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE){
            Element myElement = (Element) myNode;

            NodeList categoryLength = myElement.getElementsByTagName("id");               
            for (int j=0 ; j<categoryLength.getLength() ; j++){
              cateFilm.add(i,myElement.getElementsByTagName("id").item(j).getTextContent());
            }
```

Comment: You are examining a DOM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NodeList categoryLength = myElement.getElementsByTagName("id"); //get all ID elements 
Node valNode = categoryLength.getChildNodes().item(0); //get the node representing value of the id element.
String value = valNode.getNodeValue(); //value of the node is the text between the id tags.
```

XML seems invalid though.

Comment: Xml is valid if you remove the arrow , and categoryLength. **getChildNodes()** ...  not work [cannot find symbol methdo getChildNodes() ]

Comment: Even if you remove the arrow, your xml will look like.  <category><id>value<detail></detail></id></category> instead of <category><id>value</id><detail></detail></category>

Comment: So ? <detail> is a sub node of <id>

Comment: Exactly. It seems invalid to me. It does not form a proper DOM model when read by a parser.

Comment: Ok, I'm a little confused right now , so explain me , if i have a node x with value Hello and a subnode of x with value World , how should i write the XML?

Comment: Normally, you would form a proper tree structure.  An element has a value or more child elements.  You may consider introducing another element xval to indicate value of X.  <root><x><xval>hello</xval><subx>World</subx></x></root>